# regex match and replace words

Tags: java, regex

I have a date type string `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` (2018-04-18T00:00:00)

I want to match `:` and replace it with `%3a`
match `-` replace it with `%2d`

this my Regexp DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/rqpmXr/11

my output `2018%3a04%3a18T00%3a00%3a00`

my expected  output need to be like that `2018%2d04%2d18T00%3a00%3a00`

Comment: See [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters). Edit: Also, Alex is right, you may just use `s.replace("-", "%2d").replace(":", "%3a")`. This makes more sense since Java regex does not support conditional replacement patterns (like in Boost or PCRE2).

Comment: URLEncoder.encode() will do the %3a but leave the `-` which is ok if this is an attempt at url encoding.  If its not, why not just use a regular string replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String date = "2018-04-18T00:00:00";
date = date.replace("-","%2d").replace(":","%3a");
```

I think it's much easier to use String.replace() method for your case.